# Could anybody help me install OOF 1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine?

Tags: software-installation

I installed a Ubuntu virtual machine that I need to use OOF 1 (available at this link: https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/oof/ ), a programme for microstructural analysis from the NIST. I have never used Ubuntu in my life and after a couple of hours of trying I still don't even understand the readme file given in the download folder. Could anybody help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Did you install the Installing OOF2 Prerequsites?

Comment: OOF2 or OOF3D ? Please edit your question to specify OOF version.

Comment: OOF 1 if possible, it's a uni project and that's what we have on our PCs

Comment: You can download the source code tar ball(s) from https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/oof/oof1/index.html.

Comment: I don't think the generic post is much use in this situation (or with any specific question about compiling)

Comment: Besides, what's the benefit of closing questions that *could* have a specific answer if someone makes the effort to investigate properly. Why discourage that effort?

Comment: I've tried building OOF 1. No answer that is or even reasonably *could* be posted to [that very general question](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961) (which perhaps should itself be closed as too broad) even slightly approaches explaining how to build OOF 1. As with many older Fortran programs, it is not obvious how to resolve build dependencies for OOF 1 and compile it with current tools. I am pretty sure it *can* be done, but I haven't solved the problem. This should be open and get another answer explaining how to do it or (less likely, but failing that) specifically why it appears impossible.

Answer (score 3):

OOF1 : Please ask at the University how others did setup `oof1` : The code is ancient, may compile on some older OS. ( No luck with Ubuntu 16.04 : g++34, g77 was used.)

OOF2 :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev libgnomecanvas2-dev libmagick++-dev python-gtk2-dev

tar xvf oof2-2.1.14.tar.gz
cd oof2-2.1.14/
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Start oof2 : `$ oof2` → The oof2 GUI opens OK.